# Are calls to non-void methods faster if there is no assignment?

Tags: java, performance

Sometimes when I refactor my code I leave the return statement in the method even if I don't use it afterwards. And I was wondering if that's a good idea.

Let say we have a method:

```
public Date doStuff(){
     Date today = new Date();
    // some other logic
    return today;
}
```

and the use of the method is refactored from:

```
...
whatsToday = doStuff();
...
```

to:

```
...
doStuff();
...
```

Would the method itself be any faster if I refactor the method to return `void`?

Will the second call be faster if the method returns some object but no assignment happens?

Comment: considering you're just returning pointers, the speed difference should be negligible. But we'll see if someone makes a profiling for it.

Comment: something else to consider: what if your class is not the only class calling that method, but is using the returned object, and you, out of the blue, turn it into a method without returntype?

Comment: Irrelevant. Real performance comes from elsewhere, not thinking about method return types.

Comment: Couldn't agree more. I don't think that will have any noticeable difference in terms of performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you should not worry too much about micro-performance when writing a Java program. This is of course not general advice but specifically when thinking about small potential optimizations, it is normally true. It is a JVM's job to take care of profiling and optimizing your application, especially optimizations that you mention such as avoiding allocating a short-lived object or returning a value from a method.

For this purpose, the [HotSpot VM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HotSpot) (that most Java applications are executed with) ships with a very powerful [just-in-time compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) which applies a long row of optimizations on your code. For your snippet, it would normally apply a combination of [inlining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion) and [escape analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_analysis). This way, it would figure out that your return value is unused and simply remove the extra allocation. As a result, this small detail of returning a value from a method does not matter at all for your program's performance.

If you want to know some extra details, here [is a list of optimizations](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/PerformanceTechniques) that HotSpot applies. You can even use [tools for looking at the optimized machine code](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/jitwatch/) that the JVM generates for your code.

Answer (score -1):

Ideally, capturing the return type into a reference variable should by no means affect the performance; I say so because, jvm by default allocates an anonymous memory location for every transaction to be executed, thus merely assigning a name to that location should not affect the performance, but again if you are not going to use the returned value, then GC clears the memory location during its next execution, whereas if you assign a name to it, then would would be cleared only if it is de-scoped or set to null. There by better memory management. So from this perspective, we can say its a performance improvement.

Answer (score -1):

I have written the following test:

```
class Test {
    public int test() {
        return 0;
    }
    public void foo() {
        int n = test();
    }
    public void bar() {
        test();
    }
}
```

, compiled it and then disassembled using `javap -c Test.class`:

```
class Test {
  Test();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public int test();
    Code:
       0: iconst_0
       1: ireturn

  public void foo();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokevirtual #2                  // Method test:()I
       4: istore_1
       5: return

  public void bar();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokevirtual #2                  // Method test:()I
       4: pop
       5: return
}
```

As you can see the only difference in byte code level between `foo()` that uses return value and `bar()` that ignores it is (as expected) the instruction `istore_1` vs `pop`.

I can guess that there can be a very small difference in terms of performance between 2 these operations. Moreover if you do not use the value `istore_1` will probably be removed by JIT. Otherwise (if you use it) the difference of performance will depend mostly on later code that uses this value.

Comment: Byte code is merly a rather high level abstraction to describe a program to a JVM and "less byte code" does not at all result in "faster code". The JIT compiler does all kinds of stuff to make a program more efficient, performance highly depends on context, the runtime profile and the applied optimizations. Furthermore, if the JIT compiler "recognizes" a pattern, more byte code can sometimes even lead to more performant code.

Comment: @RafaelWinterhalter, I mentioned this in the last paragraph. However often byte code helps to understand what happens behind the scene.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. The byte code does not really expose more information than the Java source code does. It is merely a translation without close to zero optimizations applied. And the JIT compilation is rather complex to reason about. The generated machine code is the only reliable source for what gets executed (in a specific profile, on a specific machine and OS).